# Bootstrap Tooltip not working?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add in a tooltip to an existing splash page. I just plugged in all the relevant Bootstrap docs, but can't seem to figure out why I can't get a tooltip showing on the small grey link center left of this page - http://wearepage.com/absorb/

Can anyone help? Seems like I haven't plugged in the bootstrap.js file properly, but I can't figure out what's missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Initilize the tool tip in script

```
$('#YourButtonID').tooltip();
```

HTML:

```
<button id="btn" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</button>
```

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/0Jvq6v0VGO)

Comment: See the "Opt-in functionality" warning box on http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips : "For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in, meaning **you must initialize them yourself**."